# Cant find the end of file

Tags: java, stdin, eof

I am facing a problem when trying to find the end of file from a stdin.
I am trying to get all the numbers that are written to the concil until reaching the EOF:

1

2

3

4

EOF

My code looks as follows:

```
public void readInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).useDelimiter("n");
    ...
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    ..
    }    
}
```

So the problem that it does not terminates when reaching the EOF. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're reading from stdin, how are you indicating the end of input from the console? Are you literally typing in "EOF"?

Comment: BTW, it's console, not council :)

Comment: either CTRL-Z / CTRL-D or typing EOF

Answer (score 2):

When reading from `System.in`, you can use `CTRL-Z` on Windows and `CTRL-D` on *nix platforms to signal the `EOF`.

Also using a delimiter is usually unnecessary unless there is a specific requirement to do so. This could be simplified to:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a need for some delimiter, definitely using delimiter is a good practice. Avoiding the use of `CTRL-Z` or `CTRL-D`. Here, I've used `EOF`, `End Of File` and `end-of-file` as delimiters you can modify the delimiters based on the requirements.

```
        Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);
        CharSequence end1 = "end-of-file";
        CharSequence end2 = "EOF";
        CharSequence end3 = "End Of File";
        ArrayList<String> Arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i =0;

        while(sin.hasNext())
        {
            Arr.add(sin.nextLine());
            if( (Arr.get(i).contains(end1)) == true || (Arr.get(i).contains(end2)) == true || (Arr.get(i).contains(end3) ) == true )
            {
                i++;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
```